# Turn Currency into Integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

How to replace or convert `$ 10.000,00` into number `10000` without `$` in the beginning and `,00` in the end in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using regex replaces:

```js
var input = "$ 10.000,00";

var output = input
    .replace(/,.*/g, '') // cut off ',' and after
    .replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove non-digit characters

// or in one go:
// var output = input.replace(/,.*|\D/g, '');

output = parseInt(output, 10); // convert to Number

console.log(output); // 10000
```

Comment: is there a way to combine the ```.replace(/,.*/g, '')``` and ```.replace(/\D/g, '')``` to make it in one line?

Comment: sure, using the `|` operator: `input.replace(/,.*|\D/g, '');`

Comment: this one line solution fixed it in my case! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try string replace.

```js
let str = "$ 10.000,00";

// swap the places for , and .
let newstr = str.replace(/[.,]/g, ($1) => {
  return $1 === '.' ? ',' : '.'
})


let num = newstr.replace(/[$,]/g, "");
console.log(num)
console.log(Number(num)) // convert it into number
console.log(parseFloat(num)) // or this
```

Comment: returning IDR 100.000.00000 instead of 10000

Comment: But the `.` is at wrong place in the currency right? Its 10 dollar if we consider it by the given `.`

Comment: Maybe `.` is a thousand separator?

Comment: Then what's the `,` used for here?

Comment: Whether this format right or wrong as i mention exactly in the question its exactly ```$ 10.000,00```, i need to turn it into 10000 only, @Shubh

Comment: @juzraai yes it's decimal separator

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, could be done easily though.

```js
let price = "$ 10.000,00"

price = parseInt(price.split('.').join("").replace(/\$/g,'')).toFixed(0)
console.log(price)
```

Comment: seems more simple.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Support for more entries:

```js
const toNumber = n => parseFloat(n.replace(/(?:^\D+)?(\d+)\.(\d{3})(,(\d+))?/, "$1$2.$4"))

console.log(toNumber("$ 10.000,00"))
console.log(toNumber("$ 10.000,69"))
console.log(toNumber("$ 10.000,00"))
console.log(toNumber("10.050,00"))
console.log(toNumber("10.981"))
```